# JavaME: How to use platformRequest to use special chars

Tags: java, java-me, midp

How to use platformRequest to initiate a call involving special chars eg * or #

Example:

```
platformRequest("tel:*123#");
```

Or any alternative to platformRequest please.

**Details:**
Nokia N70
CLDC 1.0
MIDP 2.0

Comment: This is identical to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084162/j2me-platformrequest-issue).  And why is it tagged "windows-mobile"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well since `platformRequest()` accepts URL string as its argument, my guess is that the characters in that string argument must be URL encoded.

So, since the `"*"` is not a reserved character, it can stay that way. But the `"#"` must be encoded like `"%23"` because it is an "unsafe character".

And my guess is that this would work:

```
platformRequest("tel:*666%23");
```

Or you can URL encode `*` as well:

```
platformRequest("tel:%2A666%23");
```